# How to make graphics with transparent background in R using ggplot2?

Tags: r, graphics, transparency, ggplot2

I need to output ggplot2 graphics from R to PNG files with transparent background. Everything is ok with basic R graphics, but no transparency with ggplot2:

```
d <- rnorm(100) #generating random data

#this returns transparent png
png('tr_tst1.png',width=300,height=300,units="px",bg = "transparent")
boxplot(d)
dev.off()

df <- data.frame(y=d,x=1)
p <- ggplot(df) + stat_boxplot(aes(x = x,y=y)) 
p <- p + opts(
    panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA), # or theme_blank()
    panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = theme_blank()
)
#returns white background
png('tr_tst2.png',width=300,height=300,units="px",bg = "transparent")
p
dev.off()
```

**Is there any way to get transparent background with ggplot2?**

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856399/how-plot-transparent-background-ggplot), the current solution is to add `theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA))`

Comment: Please consider marking the second answer (by YRC) as accepted due to 'opts' being obsolete.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Create the initial plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
d <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1,
  y = d,
  group = rep(c("gr1", "gr2"), 50)
)
p <- ggplot(df) + stat_boxplot(
  aes(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    color = group
  ), 
  fill = "transparent" # for the inside of the boxplot
)
```

The fastest way to modify the plot above to have a completely transparent background is to set [`theme()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html)'s `rect` argument, as all the rectangle elements inherit from `rect`:

```r
p <- p + theme(rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))
          
p
```

A more controlled way is to set `theme()`'s more specific arguments individually:

```r
p <- p + theme(
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",
                                  colour = NA_character_), # necessary to avoid drawing panel outline
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(), # get rid of major grid
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), # get rid of minor grid
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",
                                 colour = NA_character_), # necessary to avoid drawing plot outline
  legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
  legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
  legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
)

p
```

---

[`ggsave()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html) offers a dedicated argument `bg` to set the

> Background colour. If `NULL`, uses the `plot.background` fill value from the plot theme.

To write a ggplot object `p` to `filename` on disk using a transparent background:

```r
ggsave(
  plot = p,
  filename = "tr_tst2.png",
  bg = "transparent"
)
```

Comment: If you don't set the `plot.background` color like the answer above your plot will have a faint outline.

Comment: Ahhh... spent too much time on not knowing last step. Saving file with ,  bg = "transparent".

Comment: I cannot believe in 2022 that ggsave is in inches and not pixels.

Comment: @jsta It's not `plot.background` but **`panel.background`** where you need to set `colour = NA`.

Comment: Addendum: My mistake, it needs to be set on *both*.

Answer (score 93):

There is also a `plot.background` option in addition to `panel.background`:

```
df <- data.frame(y=d,x=1)
p <- ggplot(df) + stat_boxplot(aes(x = x,y=y)) 
p <- p + opts(
    panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA), # or theme_blank()
    panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
    plot.background = theme_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA)
)
#returns white background
png('tr_tst2.png',width=300,height=300,units="px",bg = "transparent")
print(p)
dev.off()
```

For some reason, the uploaded image is displaying differently than on my computer, so I've omitted it. But for me, I get a plot with an entirely gray background except for the box part of the boxplot which is still white. That can be changed using the fill aesthetic in the boxplot geom as well, I believe.

**Edit**

**ggplot2** has since been updated and the `opts()` function has been deprecated. Currently, you would use `theme()` instead of `opts()` and `element_rect()` instead of `theme_rect()`, etc.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to work with a Mac when tested with that platform's current PowerPoint but it works as advertised. And it works with pdf's as well if you remove the units and substitute sizes in inches Good job.

Comment: This works excellent with MS Powerpoint 2010. Actually, I needed it right for this purpose.

Comment: If you're using ggsave, don't forget to add in `bg = "transparent"` to pass to the png graphics device.

Comment: if you're using the `knitr` package (or `slidify` etc) you need to pass `dev.args = list(bg = 'transparent')` as a chunk option.  More detail here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13826154/561698

Answer (score 6):

Just to improve YCR's answer:

1) I added black lines on x and y axis. Otherwise they are made transparent too.

2) I added a transparent theme to the legend key. Otherwise, you will get a fill there, 
   which won't be very esthetic.

Finally, note that all those work only with pdf and png formats. jpeg fails to produce transparent graphs.

```
MyTheme_transparent <- theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"), # bg of the panel
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA), # bg of the plot
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), # get rid of major grid
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), # get rid of minor grid
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"), # get rid of legend bg
    legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"), # get rid of legend panel bg
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA), # get rid of key legend fill, and of the surrounding
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black") # adding a black line for x and y axis
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Cairo package can be used to save ggplots as images with transparent backgrounds.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cairo/Cairo.pdf

```
CairoPNG(filename = "TEST.png", bg = "transparent")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+
   geom_point()+
   theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
      plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA))

dev.off()
```

Comment: Note the typo on "CaiorPNG" (r ill-located).

Answer (score 0):

As for someone don't like gray background like academic editor, try this:

```
p <- p + theme_bw()
p
```

Comment: `theme_bw` gives a white background, not a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work for those who are working within R Markdown and don't want to use `ggsave` to save a separate file.

You do the following, and just add this chunk option: `{r, dev.args = list(bg = 'transparent')}`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
   geom_point() +
   theme(
     # makes background transparent:
     plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
     # gets rid of white border around plot: 
     panel.border = element_blank() 
   )
```

For example, I am using ioslides presentation within R Markdown, though note that I have not tested this outside of this context.