# How to use a "R-generated" plot as a semi-transparent background in an HTML5 slide made by knitr?

Tags: html, r, knitr, pandoc

I want to add a plot to my first page of the (HTML5) slide. Can I achieve this in a dynamically way? Say, the background image will be generated by R code, rather than insert a semi-transparent PNG image. Thank you.

**Update**: What I want is

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the chunk option `dev.args` to achieve this. You will need to size the image correctly to fit your slide.

````
```{r dev.args = list(bg = 'transparent')}
 plot(1:10, 1:10)
```
````

This chunk will generate a transparent png. Please read the documentation `? png` to get a list of arguments you can pass. Here is one useful piece onf info from the docs.

> png supports transparent backgrounds: use bg = "transparent". (Not all PNG viewers render files with transparency correctly.)

UPDATE. For plots using `ggplot2`, the `alpha` parameter can be used to control transparency.

````
```{r dev.args = list(bg = 'transparent'), echo = F, comment = NA, message = F}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.1) + 
  geom_smooth(alpha = 0.1)
```
````

UPDATE2. To use a dynamic image as background, you need to set the background of the slide dynamically. This can be easily achieved in [slidify](http://www.slidify.org) [Disclosure: I am the author]

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/4262686) with an Rmd file which when slidified will give a transparent background.

Comment: For `ggplot2` you will have to use `alpha` to control transparency of the image. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, but the "item"s are still below the plot.

Comment: Oh I got it now. You want it as the slide background. Here is what you can do. See my edit.

Comment: Wow~ Slidify looks fantastic! I'll definitely give it a try. But I am quite confused about the tool chain: Slidify, knitr, Rmd, md, pandoc and slides. My comprehension is: knitr implements Rmd; Rmd provides R extension (execute code chunk, etc) to md; pandoc convert md to slides. Can I say Slidify is a powerful extension to knitr?

Comment: To use LaTeX, are there anything necessary besides setting `widgets: mathjax`?

Comment: @ziyuang You are right in that `slidify` is a wrapper around `knitr` and `markdown` that makes it easy to generate html slides from R markdown.