# Remove whitespace around pie chart generated by ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I'm saving a pie chart generated by ggplot with ggsave:

```
            pie <-ggplot(data.pie, aes(x = "", y=value, fill = target)) + 
                  geom_bar(width=1,stat="identity") +
                  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
                  theme(legend.position = "none",
                         panel.background = element_blank(),
                         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                         panel.margin = unit(0,"null"),
                         plot.margin = rep(unit(0,"null"),4),
                         axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                         axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                         axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                         axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                         axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                         axis.ticks.length = unit(0,"null"),
                         axis.ticks.margin = unit(0,"null")) +
                  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
                  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))

        ggsave(file=filename, plot=pie, width=8, height=8)
```

As you may see I've tried to remove the whitespace from the generated .svg file, but without succes.

[image: Pie chart with whitespace]

The goal is to remove all of the whitespace so I can place this image on top of another image without the ugly whitespace around.

Comment: Have you tried adding `plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA))`?

Comment: @tonytonov Yes. Unfortunately, that doesn't do the trick.

Comment: There's another hint: `bg = "transparent"` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455046/how-to-make-graphics-with-transparent-background-in-r-using-ggplot2).

Comment: @tonytonov Yes! That did the trick.

Comment: also, you might want to have a look at the new svglite https://github.com/hadley/svglite for saving as svg