# Any way to plot multiple barplots on a map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, ggmap

I'm attempting to plot multiple barplots on a map and am just looking for a place to start. I've looked at a few questions already (shown below)..

[Barplots on a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465070/barplots-on-a-map)

[Plotting bar charts on map using ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028659/plotting-bar-charts-on-map-using-ggplot2)

[How to plot barchart onto ggplot2 map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063043/how-to-plot-barchart-onto-ggplot2-map)

However, all of these seem out of date.

Below is the data I am trying to plot. I'm looking to make 4 plots on one map with one in each geolocation. I want each plot to be a barpot of counts for each purpose at each respective location.

```
                 geoloc                     purpose count
1      Eastern Atlantic                    Behavior     4
2      Eastern Atlantic           Impacts/Fisheries     7
3      Eastern Atlantic                   Knowledge     8
4      Eastern Atlantic Migration/Habitat Selection     2
5      Eastern Atlantic                    Movement    10
7       Eastern Pacific                    Behavior     1
8       Eastern Pacific           Impacts/Fisheries     1
9       Eastern Pacific                   Knowledge     3
10      Eastern Pacific Migration/Habitat Selection     2
11      Eastern Pacific                    Movement     4
13 Southwestern Pacific                    Behavior     3
14 Southwestern Pacific                    Movement     7
15     Western Atlantic                    Behavior     8
16     Western Atlantic           Impacts/Fisheries     2
17     Western Atlantic                   Knowledge     8
18     Western Atlantic Migration/Habitat Selection     3
19     Western Atlantic                    Movement     9
```

This is how I obtained the map I am trying to use

```
mp <-  NULL
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray70", fill="gray70") 
mp <- ggplot() +   mapWorld
```

I would like to be able to do this in ggplot2/ggmap since that is what I am used to, but would be happy to learn other solutions!

This is similar to what I am trying to do (from Memarzadeh et al. 2019).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally use the magick package to treat the graphs as images, and merge the images with the desired offsets to create something that resembles your goal. I created a very quick example which shows you how this might work to place two bar graphs on the world map [image: only showing Atlantic and Pacific for now]

Obviously, you could perform further manipulation to add a legend, graph titles etc. Here is the code I  used

```
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)
mp <-  NULL
mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="gray70", fill="gray70") 

fig <- image_graph(width = 850, height = 550, res = 96)
ggplot() + mapWorld
dev.off()

df1 <- data.frame(name = c('A','B','C'), value = c(10,12,13))
df2 <- data.frame(name = c('A','B','C'), value = c(8,12,18))

bp1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())

bp2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())

barfig1 <- image_graph(width = 100, height = 75, res = 72)
bp1
dev.off()

barfig2 <- image_graph(width = 100, height = 75, res = 72)
bp2
dev.off()

final <- image_composite(fig, barfig1, offset = "+75+150")
final <- image_composite(final, barfig2, offset = "+325+125")
final
```

Comment: Any way to make plot backgrounds transparent? I've been trying examples from this post that haven't been working for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455046/how-to-make-graphics-with-transparent-background-in-r-using-ggplot2

Comment: Figured it out.. You have to set all themes to blank as well as add a "bg = 'transparent' argument to the image_graph function.

Comment: Glad that worked! An alternative would be to convert the "barfig" images to transparent after creating them, using barfig1 <- image_transparent(barfig1, 'white'). This will also be more effective if you remove gridlines first

Comment: Any way to utilize the white space below the plot or doing a two panel plot with this? I'd like to add another figure below the map.

Comment: You can stack multiple magick images quite easily (this has more info if you want to read more into it https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html). First, make a vector of images - you can test it with the same image twice, so stacked <- c(final, final). To create a stacked image, the general code is stacked <- image_append(image_scale(stacked, "x1000"), stack = TRUE)